# Keeping $attributes but adding a rel (D7)

Tags: theming, navigation

I have the following piece of code:

```
l('<div class="magnifier gradient"></div>' . $image, $link_path, array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => $attributes))
```

Which creates a nice link, as it should be. Now I want to add a rel-attribute without getting rid off $attributes (because I need that one). I have Googled and tried a lot, but nothing seems to work. So if anyone can help me with just adding a rel-attribute without deleting the other attributes, I would be grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right you just want to add the `rel` attribute to the `$attributes` array before you call `l()`. Something like this:

```
$attributes['rel'] = 'the_rel';
print l('<div class="magnifier gradient"></div>' . $image, $link_path, array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => $attributes));
```

That will add the an item to the `$attributes` array with a key of `rel` and a value of `the_rel`, and won't affect any of the other attributes already in the array.